# How can I delete multply rows from a table with another condition?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this:

```
1   Apple    1
2   Apple    null
3   Apple    2
4   Orange   1
5   Orange   2
6   Pear     null
7   Lemon    1
8   Lemon    null
```

I want to delete a row if it's ProductId is null and if it's Name is occurs more than once.

At this example if I run a proper delete query, it should delete these rows:

```
2   Apple    null
8   Lemon    null
```

Which kind of delete query can work for me?

Comment: Which exact SQL? (MYSQL, Access, Oracle...)

Comment: Database is mysql

Comment: I've solved this problem with answer of harrymc, thank you too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the capabilities of your SQL engine, you might be able to
run something like the following:

```
Delete from Products PID where ProductId is null and
  exists(select * from Products where Name=PID.Name and ProductId is not null)
```

Otherwise you will need to create a temporary table or view for products whose
ProductId is not null.